# Convert a div to a image in ionic 3

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3

I am working in ionic 3 environment

where i have a div as

```
<div id = "sample">
<p> This is a sample div </p>
</div>
```

Now i just want to covert this div into a image and should be able to display as

```
<img id = "converted_div_into_image">
```

I got an option of **html to png npm package**, but without it can we able to convert into image without any other sources?

Comment: You mean to ask without any library?

Comment: Yes right without librabry

Answer (score 0):

Try this library to convert HTML to a canvas.

- http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/